# CakePHP Required Fields - Not Making Any Sense

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a form that it seems to me Cake is making fields required or not required so randomly that I can't even control it.  Please help me to understand how to get required fields working.

```
public $validate = array(
    'fname' => array(
        'rule1' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please enter your first name'
        ),
        'rule2' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', '50'),
            'message' => 'First name cannot exceed 50 characters'
        )
    ),
    'sname' => array(
        'rule1' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please enter your last name'
        ),
        'rule2' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', '50'),
            'message' => 'Last name cannot exceed 50 characters'
        ),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'rule1' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please enter your email address'
        ),
        'rule2' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 100),
            'message' => array('Email cannot exceed 100 characters')
        ),
        'rule3' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address'
        ),
        'rule4' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'An account already exists with that email address',
            'on' => 'update'
        )
    )
);
```

All these 3 fields cannot be empty, but Cake is deciding to make `fname` and `sname` show as required on the form, but email is not required. I'm talking about the class on the inputs making it look required. This is so random.  In the database the fields are all identical VARCHAR, NOT NULL.

I tried adding `allowEmpty => false` to the email but it doesn't do anything.  This works on other fields that only have one rule but doesn't work on fields that have multiple rules.  Still, I want to know why it is making fname and sname required but not email.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/imeqW.gif

Comment: I am running cakephp 2.0.6 and I don't see the same thing. Will you provide the view file you are using too? Maybe there is something in the form that is making it style change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi in the table for email field make it as could not be

> NULL

(I think email column can accept null values like that u created the table) then it Required * symbol will come on view. Surely it will work, I face the same issue like this

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'required'=true on the rules of the fields you want to be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off all of the email validation rules by:

```
unset($this->ModelName->validate['email']);
```

But after watching the screenshoot,i can see that there is no red star above email field.The cause of this maybe you didn't properly named the email input

```
echo $this->Form->input('email');
```

Normally if you have this line(if it is generated by bake than must be right),it must have the validation rules for email field